# Package breaks when upgrading from Debian stable to testing

Tags: debian, apt

After reading that Debian testing is more popular with desktop users than Debian stable, i decided to upgrade from stable to testing.  I replaced all instances of "jessie" with "testing" with the command "sed -i 's/jessie/stable/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.  Then, I did the upgrade with the command "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade".  Now, when I try to install packages or upgrade, I get the following output:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.123) but 1.156 is installed
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.123) but 1.156 is installed
 libpurple-bin : Depends: libpurple0 but it is not installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 215-17+deb8u5) but 232-8 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 215-17+deb8u5) but 232-8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So naturally, I followed the instructions and tried using -f:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.123) but 1.156 is installed
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.123) but 1.156 is installed
 libpurple-bin : Depends: libpurple0 but it is not installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 215-17+deb8u5) but 232-8 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 215-17+deb8u5) but 232-8 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I get a similar error when trying to install individual packages.  Here is what my sources.list looks like:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160609-14:12]/ testing contrib main non-free

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160609-14:12]/ testing contrib main non-free

deb http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ testing main 
deb-src http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ testing main 

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free

# testing-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

So, any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Debian testing is more popular with desktop users than Debian stable

I strongly disagree with this statement.

Debian testing & unstable are *development branches* and are not intended for normal usage, those versions are supposed to be used for bug-hunting and, as such, cannot be expected to be completely functional on a consistent basis.

Testing and unstable are *not* simply "Debian stable with newer packages", the paradigm is completely different and almost diametrically opposed to that used for the stable release.

If newer package versions are required, I would recommend using the jessie-backports repositories instead [1] or waiting until Debian 9.0 is released later in the year.

[1] https://backports.debian.org/

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've tried changing 'testing' in my sources.list file back to 'jessie', but it seems that going back to jessie isn't that simple.  How would I go about going back to stable without completely reinstalling?

Comment: You can't go back, you should re-install instead. EDIT: or restore your backup.

Answer (score 0):

apt is not designed to downgrade a Distro-version. But maybe you can do it with apt-pinning.

Generate the file

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/jessie-preferences

    Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian                                                  

Pin-Priority: 1001
```

the last command is a simulation.

`apt update && apt --dry-run dist-upgrade` When no Package-conflicts you can do it without --dry-run. It can work but it can also not work. Backup first.

too fast. After that remove the file.

Comment: `apt` *can* downgrade packages, it's the packages themselves which aren't designed to be downgraded. It may work, but there's no requirement for downgrades to be supported. So you can force downgrades with `apt`, but you might break your system...